# Автоматизация Sass, Emmet

Tags: sublime-text, sass, автоматизация, emmet

Всем привет! Подскажите Как автоматизировать написание вон такого кода?

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
1px 1px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
2px 2px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
3px 3px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
4px 4px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
5px 5px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
6px 6px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
7px 7px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
8px 8px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
9px 9px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
10px 10px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
11px 11px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
12px 12px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
13px 13px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
14px 14px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
15px 15px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
16px 16px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1),
17px 17px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1)
```

*PS: там еще много строк просто чтоб не флудить не дублировал)*

Comment: **Первый вариант**: **a)** Устанавливаете [**PasteRepeater**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PasteRepeater), повторяете с помощью этого плагина строку `1px 1px 0px rgba(0,191,170, 1)` столько раз, сколько Вам нужно. // **б)** Устаналиваете какой-нибудь плагин для инкрементальной замены. я пользуюсь [**Incrementor**](https://github.com/born2c0de/Incrementor), есть ещё, например, [**Multifill**](https://github.com/Lellansin/MultiFill). Применяя регулярные выражения, делаете замену. Как проводить операции с плагинами, читайте по ссылкам, что Вам дал.

Comment: **Второй вариант**: Emmet также имеет инкрементор. Синтаксис: `$*20`, где `$` — переменная, `20` — сколько раз нужно повторить. Примеры использования см. в книге [**«Sublime Text Power User»**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaBooks/blob/master/IT/Sublime%20Text/Sublime%20Text%20Power%20User.pdf#page=148). Если что-то непонятно, пишите в комментариях. Спасибо.

Comment: Это тебе спасибо) Установил себе "Incrementor" с задачей он справился) Благодарю!

Comment: junior-web-dev, Incrementor более универсальное решение, тогда как для Emmet нужно знать, как он функционирует в различных языках. Но Incrementor может сбоить, см. [**мой старый багрепорт**](https://github.com/born2c0de/Incrementor/issues/3#issuecomment-243970091). // Задача решается и другими способами. Поиск по слову [**Increment**](https://packagecontrol.io/search/increment). Спасибо.

Comment: Разве в Emmet можно написать код как в примере с text-shadow ? Не представляю куда там засунуть $ чтобы он просчитал инкрементом смещения тени. На счет багов буду иметь ввиду, спасибо.